# JavaScript Flash Embed Error

Tags: javascript, flash, embed

hi i have the following page: [here][link removed]

the script i wrote is working fine. but the script attached to the flash player which i have no control over is throwing a script error (im using IE8).

any ideas as to how can i fix this? if i run it locally there is no error.

thanks.

**EDIT:**

says

> 'null' is null or not an object

```
try { document.getElementById("").SetReturnValue(__flash__toXML(function() { return document.location.hostname; }()) ); } catch (e) { document.getElementById("").SetReturnValue("<undefined/>"); }
```

but this is from flash script and i dont have control over it. it just say JScript - script block.

Comment: Please quote the error in question and the line that throws it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed `<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>`

to: `<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="never"/>`

and the bug went away!

thanks.

**SOLVED:** the provided embed code was missing ID tag. that was the problem.